# Opinion on User Experience - C# Winforms

Tags: c#, backgroundworker, user-experience

I’ve got a process which will take a little under 5 seconds to complete.  The user will most likely notice the program flicker for a few seconds after pushing the “go” button.

My question is:

Is this something that would normally be dumped onto a background worker, or is there another .NET method for handling small tasks, or is this something that shouldn’t be a concern?

FYI:
The process opens a user specified excel file, processes an unknown number of lines (max 1.5 million due to excel I believe), and queries a database (very quick query).  So at the worst case scenario the user uploads a 1.5 million row excel file and is running on a very slow internet connection.

Comment: loading 1.5 million rows on a very slow Internet connection in under 5 seconds??

Comment: Yes, use a background worker (too short to be an answer)

Comment: @Serge He's using a revolutionary data transfer compression algorythm...why are you putting that in doubt?? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want the user to be able to do anything while the file is being uploaded, then you don't need to put it on a different thread.

If you want the user to be able to go on to other tasks while the file is uploading, put it on a different thread.

As a general rule of thumb, if I have a situation where I absolutely don't want the user to do anything while a long-running process is going, I disable the controls on the form until the task is complete, and usually use a status indicator to show that progress is happening.

My personal guideline for whether or not to allow user interaction is if the results of a process could be altered by a user action in mid-stream.

For example, one program that we have parses a bunch of queries on a highly normalized database (normalized to the point where reporting is sloooow) into "reportable" tables, and I don't want the user altering data in one of the source tables while the query is running, because it will give goofy results.

If there is no harm in allowing user interaction while the process is occuring, then put it in another thread.

**Edit**

Actually, on reading @UrbanEsc and @archer's comments, I agree with them.  Still put it on a different thread and freeze the controls (and include a progress indicator where possible).

Comment: I would still put it on a background thread and disable the controls or whatever to not allow manipulation or otherwise the application will freeze and unresponsive (become white) in those 5 seconds. Definatly not good.

Comment: When you don't want user do anything, anyway need to put such tasks on different thread, because otherwise window can't be even minimized.

Comment: This is a better answer then just saying put it on a background thread.  +1 for adding some context

Answer (score 1):

I would push this to a background worker. Doing so will keep the UI responsive. If the process ever does lag for more than a few seconds, users start getting nervous ...especially when the lagging process causes the UI to be 'frozen'.

Answer (score 1):

From a user experience point of view it might be best to hand the job over to a different thread or an asynchronous worker and tell the user that his request is being processed in the background. Once the worker finishes, a success/failure message can be handled and shown to the user as required.

Answer (score 1):

The cheapest way to handle the problem is to turn the cursor into an hourglass during the processing. That tells user *please wait, I'm busy*.

According to the budget (time and/or effort) you're willing to throw in it, using a backgroundworker and some reporting GUI is certainly a plus. But it's up to you according to your app.

For example, I'm currently modifying an in-house app that has 3 users. In that case, the hourglass is OK: All 3 of them will quickly learn they just have to wait. Don't get me wrong: this app is damn important. Without it, the small company that uses it would just die. But if I ask them for 2 hours of extra budget for a nice and tested little GUI, background thread, blah vs an hourglass, what do you think they'll say?

On the other hand, if it's an important operation in your flagship product, of course be nice to your users! Don't hesitate: background thread. Especially if the operation may actually take much longer than those 5 seconds.

**Conclusion: Be pragmatic!**

Answer (score 0):

I would put it into a background worker or fire of a task if you are in .NET 4.0, for example:

```
void OnButtonClick(...)
{
    new TaskFactory().StartNew(() => { /* your excel and query code */ });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll vote for the background worker process, since a frozen UI is like a frozen application, and most of users will think your application isn't doing anything at all.

**UI thread for a progress bar or some animation, info text noticing what's going on** + **background worker thread** = *win*

Answer (score 0):

I think every process not related with the UI itself should be started as a separate thred or, in this case, as a bg worker. This will help to maintain the app healthy and easy to improve/fix in the future.

Also, as a user or tester, I really hate flicking and freezing windows...

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

A general rule of thumb is any operation that takes a second or longer to complete requires some form of feedback to the user.  This can be a progress bar, message, etc.  Anything longer then that then the user becomes frustrated (not sure if they did something wrong, hate waiting, etc).

For operations like this that can take longer based on the environment (number of apps, available memory, data size, hard drive speed, etc) they should ALWAYS be put on a background thread and pipe messages back to the UI.  I love the BackGroundWorker for this.